# Next.js error: Unexpected token 'export' for next/server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I am getting `Unexpected token 'export'` when trying to `yarn dev` my Nextjs project. Here is the error message I am getting (after running `yarn build`).

```
> Build error occurred
/Users/.../my-repo/node_modules/next/server.js:1
export { NextRequest } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../my-repo/node_modules/@clerk/nextjs/dist/server/utils.js:5:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14) {
  type: 'SyntaxError'
}
```

This is what `node_modules/next/server.js` looks like in my project.

```
export { NextRequest } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request'
export { NextResponse } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/response'
```

Also, here is `next.config.js`:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  eslint: {
    dirs: ["."],
  },
  poweredByHeader: false,
  trailingSlash: true,
  basePath: "",
  env: {
    PROJECT_NAME: process.env.PROJECT_NAME,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(nextConfig);
```

I have already tried using `next-transpile-modules`, but this did not help. For reference, I am (and need to be) using v12.1.0 of `next`, so I can't take advantage of the in-built transpile support that v13.1 comes with.

What could the problem be?

Comment: change ***export*** to ***import***

Answer (score 1):

I think you're importing some components but you're using wrong syntax!
You need to change `export { NextRequest } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request'` to `import { NextRequest } from 'next/dist/server/web/spec-extension/request'` .

Please Check the Documentation for Further Information on NextJS Docs.

Answer (score 0):

problem of version
Then, run the following command to update React:
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
if found error add --force